# Connecting flight in Amsterdam to Bergen

Tags: schengen, transit, layovers, ams, connecting-flights

I am travelling from Delhi to Bergen via Amsterdam. There is a 4-hour layover. I have to catch a KLM flight to Bergen, Norway.

Where will I collect my baggage? Can I go directly to the gate or is a bus required? I saw somewhere that you are taken by bus to the corresponding gates.

Answer (score 2):

If the two flights are booked together, your baggage will almost certainly be checked through to Bergen, and you will not see it in Amsterdam.

When you arrive at Amsterdam, follow the signs for Connecting Flights.  You will pass through transfer security and end up in the non-Schengen transit area.  At this point, look up your connecting flight on the departure monitors and follow the signs towards the appropriate gate/pier.  Along the way, this will lead you through passport controls for Schengen immigration.

All the concourses in Amsterdam are in a single terminal complex with walkable connections between them.  No busing will be involved -- except possibly an apron bus *from* your departure gate *to* a remote aircraft stand, as part of the boarding process.

Comment: When I traveled from Amsterdam to Bergen earlier this year, there was indeed a bus taking us from the gate to the aircraft. Not sure if that's a regular thing, or if there was no space at the gates at the time. In my experience, buses are a rare thing at Amsterdam though.